# https is not working with my installed ssl (nginx & letsencrypt)

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, server, cloudflare

I have installed ssl certificate using letsencrypt in my `nginx` server. It works perfectly in the following domain:
http://shajao.com

Site gets redirected perfectly and ssl is working nicely with an A+ score in ssllabs.

I followed this instruction:
https://medium.com/@jnwarp/lets-encrypt-configure-nginx-with-a-perfect-score-on-ssl-labs-6fc10d2e4bf7

I tried to do the same thing on same server but different domain name but can't get it to work.
Basically ssl is not working. So when I hit the domain in browser it starts an infinite redirection loop. So I stopped the http to https redirect and found that https is not working which gets the site redirected to http.

My dns is managed using cloudflare and I tried turning off the ssl feature from there as well.

[image: Cloudflare ssl off]

My server code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name getcoursetube.com www.getcoursetube.com;
    root /media/6sense/www/getcoursetube.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    #   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    root /media/6sense/www/getcoursetube.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name getcoursetube.com www.getcoursetube.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }

    error_log /media/6sense/www/getcoursetube.com/logs/error.log;
    access_log /media/6sense/www/getcoursetube.com/logs/access.log;
    
    #WARNING: Please read before adding the lines below!
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; 
    includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/getcoursetube.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/getcoursetube.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chain.pem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours, I tested my certificate on DigiCert. And found that DigiCert is showing a SSL certificate that is issued by Cloudflare.

I turned off SSL from Cloudflare but it didn't work. So I had to quit Cloudflare. 
I removed my site from Cloudflare and managed my DNS through GoDaddy (from where I purchased my domain). And it worked perfectly.

Let me know if anybody has a better answer and made it work through Cloudflare as well.

**Update:**

I readded my domain on Cloudflare and set SSL to full mode in Cloudflare. Removed the redirection code from Nginx server configuration and enabled always https on Cloudflare. And everything started working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

the reason for me was i didnt allow inbound traffic to the port 443 on my instance.